# Implication of confession in F/X2 (1991)

Tags: plot-explanation, fx2

When Neely confesses to the priest that he had anger towards an old man that was his friend, is this implying that Neely actually killed Becker?

Comment: I'm not sure why we have downvotes and close votes here - I'm assuming someone that knows the movie, that this would make complete sense.  It seems clear enough to me.

Comment: It has been a while, but I always personally have been taking the words "he had anger" as euphemism for "I've tortured old friend". But Becker was already basically dying at this stage from natural causes, so it is unclear what in the end has killed him.

Comment: That is not how I understood it. I thought the moment was intended to be humorously ironic (confessing to trivial sins while executing, effectively, a heist from the church). A confession to murder wouldn’t have fit with that. I think the guy just died.